# I can not access internet on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, firefox

These error messages are from firefox when starting it whit wired connection:

> Log in to network
>
> You must log in to this network before you can access the Internet.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not
>   possible to add an exception for this certificate.
>
> Your connection is not secure

This message is when requesting to visit the askubuntu.com

> The owner of askubuntu.com has configured their website improperly. To
>   protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected
>   to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not
>   possible to add an exception for this certificate.
>
> https://askubuntu.com/ Unable to communicate securely with peer:
>   requested domain name does not match the server’s certificate.
>
> HTTP Strict Transport Security: true
>
> HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

This one is when requesting to visit www.google.com

> www.google.se uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is
>   only valid for the following names: *.ownit.se, ownit.se
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
>
> https://www.google.se/ Unable to communicate securely with peer:
>   requested domain name does not match the server’s certificate.
>
> HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
>
> HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

The connection changes between connected and disconnected for a short while.

These questions are those which could explain why there is no access to internet:

-am I behind a firewall ?

-is this a case of captive portal?

-or something else which I don't understand??

I need to know how to fix them?

Comment: Yes, looks to me like you're behind a captive portal or your-modem-is-not-connected error page or something like that. Try accessing some http (not https) page and that'll avoid the cert problems and let you see the page it's trying to show you.

Comment: I visited this site, http://www.stealmylogin.com , there was not a login page, instead the connection was redirected to ownit.se

Answer (score 0):

The last error looks to be using `*.ownit.se, ownit.se`. Is ownit.se your ISP (internet service provider)? I looked at the page in Google and they appear to be, but did not see much information. If you do not have any relation to them, I would be very careful.

They are attempting to hijack your web browser page, possibly to enter a username/password, or accept some terms before allowing any use of the provided internet connection. However modern browsers are designed to block that where possible as it can be used maliciously, e.g. to give a 3rd party your bank details, etc. by tricking you when you try and visit your banks website.

You could try visiting http://ownit.se or https://ownit.se directly. As that is there own website Firefox may accept it.

Any http page should work, but sites are increasingly going https only to stop various attacks, giving you the HSTS errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the Ownit.se is my internet service provider. I have used public wi-fi on a public library, efter that firefox has not allowed any connection neither wierd nor wireless.

Comment: And if you visit ownit.se in Firefox what happens?

Comment: The log in page is coming up as I pasted at the begining of my answer,

Comment: Should be without any "This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate." so that you can enter the requested details and then procede. Maybe not clear/understanding, screenshot?

Comment: Tried to add an exception as well but Firefox does not accept that,

Comment: For `https://ownit.se` https://ownit.se  ? Screenshot?

Comment: I am sorry I am late to answer your question, those text which are highlighted are error massages from Firefox that I have copied and then pasted in my question, I was recommanded to do it this way instead of pasting screenshots.

Comment: For `https://ownit.se` and not `http://ownit.se` or similar? Never seen one of these network login hooks complain about its own address. What is the exact URL in your address bar (maybe a redirect) and if there is an "Advanced" button, does that show anything extra for that specific address?

Comment: There is not an Advance button when starting the URL https://active.ownit.se/wrong, ther is Ann start page button which stays at the same URL. Visning askubuntu shows an ”open Network login page”, there is an advacance button here and it shows ” Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN ”

Comment: `https://ownit.se` redirects to `https://active.ownit.se/wrong` and displays an actual page, but doesn't work right? Show that page, what visiting other sites does I don't think matters.